# Posting a comment causes a page within the page

Tags: bug, status-norepro, comments

When I added comment in post. Instead of showing me comment. Stack Overflow generated the index page in comments section. This is not the first time I saw that but I have seen this many times.

[image: This is what I got:]

Comment: Btw, You haven't associated you both accounts :)

Comment: @hims056 do you know how can I ?

Comment: Just see [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18232/187824)

Comment: Whoah, looks like the AJAX failed. Never seen that myself, but you've got yourself one hell of a bug.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII i have got this bug many times.But this time, i got a screenshot so, I prefer it to add here so, stackoverflow can remove it. :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sorry, but there's no way I can see this happening, so I'll have to assume that this is a problem on your end (my first guess would be a horribly broken proxy).

I have checked the logs; your request when posting the comment was recorded by the load balancer to have received a response of 786 bytes in size. That sounds about right for the expected response (the list of then-present comments, which is then inserted in the appropriate place), but is orders of magnitude below the size that a response containing the full home page would have had.

So something between us and your browser replaced the response. Note in particular that this misplaced homepage in your screenshot has a "log in" link. Had *your browser* requested that page, it would have had your name at the top, since you were logged in.